# Java - way to prevent Collections Framework use for assignment?

Tags: java, collections

For a particular assignment (in Java), I'm having my students implement some ADTs, and I am preventing them from using any of the Java Collections Framework that we have covered previously (List, Collections, LinkedList, Stack, Deque, etc.).

What are some good ways to enforce / detect this restriction to make sure they are not using these interfaces and classes for this particular assignment?

Is there a compiler directive / switch / setting to prevent usage of `java.util` entirely? I mean, that's some serious hobbling, but for this assignment so far it can get by on just `java.lang`. I would have liked to used `Iterator`, and they need to have Generics.

I was going to try to detect `import` statements, but reflection can't get those from the byte code. One post suggested [QDox](https://github.com/paul-hammant/qdox) on source files for getting imports, but I didn't want to load an additional library for this. Should I just write a script to scan their source files for `java.util.x` imports?

I was thinking of looking at their class files with reflection to see if any members where of those list of types... but kinda messy :/

Most of my assignments are auto-graded / unit-tested because of the number of students, though for some assignments I peek at all the code to give them additional feedback. So for now, I have to do that on this one just to catch those who didn't follow directions.

Just curious what some of you would do for this.

Comment: How devious are your students? You don't need any imports at all to use any class, just using the fully qualified classname is adequate.

Comment: this is a great point I forgot about lol

Comment: Yes, and I do my job well, judged my thousands of very successful graduates and very high reviews in non-trivial courses, the amount of time I spend working with them, and the fact that I'm helping my students literally between typing this in the middle of the night on a Discord server. But as you may know (or not apparently), when you have hundreds of programs to grade every few weeks, we (smart) teachers do little things to automate certain aspects of that burden, such as run scripts to check for obvious not following of directions, etc. Sawee u so gwumpy :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of dependency analysers available, but if you are using a recent JDK, `jdeps` (part of the JDK since 8) might be sufficient for your needs.

For example:

```
$ jdeps -verbose:class -p java.util ~/opt/antlrworks/antlrworks-1.5.2-complete.jar
```

lists the dependencies on `java.util.*` classes. Should be easy to call it from a small shell script or similar for automatic checking.

It is not impossible to get around detection by using reflection (`Class.forName`...), but if any of your students manage/know how to do this, they deserve a bonus point anyway. ;-)

More info is available here: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you! There are so many useful tools that come with the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this would be to make use of checkstyle, and turn on the 'IllegalImport' rule.  https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#IllegalImport

Simply add the classes you want to disallow to the list, and if they are present in the code, the build will fail.